# What's the difference between an application launcher and type in an application name and run it from teriminal?

Tags: linux, qt

I have a QT application. When I use my created application launcher to start it, it doesn't work.

However, if I go to terminal and run the application from there, it works.

I'm wondering what their differences are.

Thanks.

Comment: Check "Exec" entry in the .desktop file. If you run that command as in "Exec" entry is the application fine?

Comment: The command in "Exec" entry is the same as I run in terminal.

Comment: Oh... full path I assume and it runs fine is it? Is there any file or other resource needed by the executable by any chance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your application launcher doesn't contain the right command and environment?

Comment: Environment, and in particular `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` would be my first guess as well.

Comment: No, the application launcher that I created is "Application in Terminal". And, I used the same cmd. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is empty. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How is your launcher trying to start the program? Are any errors being reported?

It could be that the current directory is not set as expected. Or the command line parameters being sent aren't formatted correctly. Hard to say without seeing some code or an error message.

Comment: I don't see any error showing by double clicking the icon. Also, there is no parameter associated with this application.